# How to install AEM components?

Tags: aem

I am just starting with Adobe Experience manager version 6.0 and wanted to install this:

https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples

I tried :

```
mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage
```

But getting this error, any ideas anyone?

[image]

Another screenshot:

[image]

m2.conf:

```
main is org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli from plexus.core

set maven.home default ${user.home}/m2

[plexus.core]
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/conf/logging
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual failure error lines. should be above the ones you have snapshot

Comment: @AmeeshTrikha see above

Comment: I am running the current master from Github on `java version "1.7.0_79"` and maven version `Apache Maven 3.3.9`. Build runs successfully for me. Can you try with - `mvn --update-plugins -U clean install`

Comment: I got exactly the same versions and tried it still the same error

Comment: Can you try by deleting the bundle plugin jar from your .m2

Comment: my m2.conf you mean? it looks like this see above

Comment: Y do you need explicitly - [plexus.core]
optionally ${maven.home}/lib/ext/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/lib/*.jar
load       ${maven.home}/conf/logging

Comment: I removed the whole plexus.core section, still no dice:(

Comment: how about removing the whole maven repository directory for a while (just rename it to repository_sthElse) and then run the build.